# サイトアイコンがポルトガル語版のアイコンになっている箇所がある

Tags: バグ, 完了, デザイン

### 左上のネットワークメニューの「現在のコミュニティ」欄

[image: ネットワークメニュー]

### メタでのプロフィールにある「メイン ユーザー」リンク

URL: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/30/ento

[image: メインユーザー]

どちらも `.favicon-ja` クラスによって見た目が設定されています。

### モバイル版のfavicon

[image: Chromeにて]

Comment: モバイル版のfaviconを追加しました

Comment: モバイル版のバグも登録しました。